# How to Fix Divide on sum from different group by

Tags: mysql, sql

anyone can help me, why this code didn't work if I put "GROUP BY DATE"

sample value of DATE is 201810,201811,201812,201901 etc

if I remove "GROUP BY DATE", its work but, will SUM all row
I want SUM totaluser group by all provinces by date, any ideas?

```
SELECT DATE AS dates,
   parProvinces.id AS provinceId, 
   parProvinces.name AS province,   
   sum(totaluser) AS countUser,     
   ( SELECT 
         SUM(totalUser)         
         FROM dsMonthlyDemographies         
         GROUP BY DATE  // <<<<-- this is didn't
   ) AS totalUserPerMonths

FROM dsMonthlyDemographies, parProvinces 
WHERE (provincesId = parProvinces.id) 
GROUP BY provinceId, dates 
ORDER BY dates ASC, provinceId ASC
```

message error:

**Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row**

**UPDATE**

this is sample data from dsMonthlyDemographies

[image: table dsMonthlyDemographies]

table parProvinces

[image: table parProvinces]

Comment: Please add some sample data which would help to explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok

Comment: Show table `parProvinces` too

Comment: @tcadidot0 done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a scalar subquery

```
SELECT DATE AS dates,
   parProvinces.id AS provinceId, 
   parProvinces.name AS province,   
   sum(totaluser) AS countUser,     
   ( SELECT 
         SUM(totalUser)         
         FROM dsMonthlyDemographies b where a.date=b.date        
   ) AS totalUserPerMonths

FROM dsMonthlyDemographies a join parProvinces on a.provincesId = parProvinces.id
GROUP BY provinceId, dates 
ORDER BY dates ASC, provinceId ASC
```

OR

```
select * from 
(SELECT DATE AS dates,
   parProvinces.id AS provinceId, 
   parProvinces.name AS province,   
   sum(totaluser) AS countUser     
   FROM dsMonthlyDemographies a join parProvinces on a.provincesId =parProvinces.id
   GROUP BY provinceId, dates 
)A inner join 
( SELECT 
         dates,SUM(totalUser)         
         FROM dsMonthlyDemographies group by dates   
 ) AS B on A.dates=b.dates
```

NOTE: It's always best to use explicit join rather than a comma separated join

Comment: this is work, but **Execution Time : 1 min 22 sec**

Comment: @RAVIBANGKITNURZIKRILLAH, I've provided another solution you can try with that

Answer (score 1):

Hi friend you just add `b.provincesId = dsMonthlyDemographies.provincesId` like below:

```
SELECT DATE AS dates,
   parProvinces.id AS provinceId, 
   parProvinces.name AS province,   
   sum(totaluser) AS countUser,     
   ( SELECT 
         SUM(b.totalUser)         
         FROM dsMonthlyDemographies  b       
         b.provincesId = dsMonthlyDemographies.provincesId
   ) AS totalUserPerMonths


    FROM dsMonthlyDemographies, parProvinces 
    WHERE (provincesId = parProvinces.id) 
    GROUP BY provinceId, dates 
    ORDER BY dates ASC, provinceId ASC
```